# Accessing AppFabric server in a workgroup

Tags: .net, appfabric, appfabric-cache

Have 2 servers on Amazon EC2. Not sure whether this is relevant. Server 1 is the app server and Server 2 is the cache server. Both are running Windows 2012. Server 1 and Server 2 do not belong to a domain. I have a matching local user with matching password on both servers. This user was granted to allowed client list

As a test, I have a console application that invokes a DataCache, puts a key, gets the same key back and echos its value. When the console application runs on the cache server, it works. However when run on the app server, it connects, can get a Cache or default cache. However fail during put operation with generic error errca0017 substatus es0006

Tried setting CacheClusterSecurity to None and None, still same behavior. Also, tried adding Everyone to the allowed client list

Any help is much appreciated. I am trying to avoid creating a domain and maintaining it in EC2 cloud if possible

Comment: Could it be the firewall, have you opened the appfabric ports?

Comment: That's the first thing we checked. We can telnet on port 22233 to the cache server. Also, we can see connectivity over WireShark

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue with a customer of mine recently.

In our case, the failure was due to a NbtNs name Lookup failure. AppFabric is configured to listen to `net.tcp://NetBIOSName:22233`. If the client is unable to resolve the NetBIOS name the PUT call fails. Underlying failure:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: No DNS entries exist for host machineName. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known

   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)

   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)

   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DnsCache.Resolve(Uri uri)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Resolution: Added machineName/IP combo into the client's host file.

UPDATE: "A workgroup scenario for AppFabric is not supported for production." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351385(v=azure.10).aspx